# Split string in python in 2 parts backwards

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

I am trying to split my string  `str = 'I HAVE 6'` in two parts. The output should be
`['I HAVE','6']`
There is no info about the length of the words given as input.
One way do this is to split it in three and add the first two. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit), which splits from the right, with a `maxsplit` of `1`:

```
s = 'I HAVE 6'
s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)  # or (' ', 1)
['I HAVE', '6']
```

As an aside, don't use the name `str`. It masks the built-in class `str` and will lead to errors down the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split()`:

```
import re
s = 'I HAVE 6'
new_s = re.split("\s(?=\d)", s)
```

Output:

```
['I HAVE', '6']
```